# use directory variable in batch command

Tags: batch-file

I am brand new to batch command. I wrote following code:

```
for /D %%G in ("C:\CI\workspace\MP*") do (
  if exists "%%~nG\DirecotoryPortal\" (
     CD "DirecotoryPortal"
     echo DirectoryPortal Exists
  )
)
```

I got the error "%~nG\DirecotoryPortal" was unexpected at this time.
I cannot figure it out how to use the %%G in the loop. I want to take this roor path and concatenate with "DirecotoryPortal" and check does the dir exists.

Comment: You should use `if exist` (not if exists).

Comment: You do not need to check if it exists, just change directory to it, subdue errors and continue only if the directory change is successful. Like this one liner: ```@For /D %%G In ("C:\CI\workspace\MP*") Do @CD /D "%%~fG\DirectoryPortal" 2>NUL && (Echo DirectoryPortal Exists)```. P.S. I spelled `Directory` properly, I could not tell from your question whether the spelling was a series of typos in your question, or a typo in the actual name of your directory; please change it should it be the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and should iterate over directories matching the pattern MP* in C:\CI\workspace.

```
for /D %%G in ("C:\CI\workspace\MP*") do (
  if exist "%%G\DirectoryPortal\" (
     CD /D "%%G\DirectoryPortal"
     echo DirectoryPortal Exists in %%G
  )
)
```

Comment: `if exist "%%G\DirectoryPortal\"` may also respond with true even the path points to a file rather than a directory, so better use `if exist "%%~G\DirectoryPortal\*"`…